# Does anyone know how to extract a date from a record in java?

Tags: java, java-me

I have a date propety set up like this

```
        cal1.setTime(StartDate.getDate());
        strStartDate = cal1.get(cal1.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                 (cal1.get(cal1.MONTH) + 1) + "/" +
                 cal1.get(cal1.YEAR);
```

And I need to extract it when a search is performed.

I so far have this

```
            int endOfName = record.indexOf(";");
            int endOfDesc = record.indexOf(";" , endOfName + 1);
            int endOfTown = record.indexOf(";", endOfDesc + 1);
            int endOfPlace = record.indexOf(";", endOfTown + 1);
            int endOfStart = record.indexOf(";", endOfPlace +1);

            String Name = record.substring(0, endOfName);
            String Desc = record.substring(endOfName + 1, endOfDesc);
            String Town = record.substring(endOfDesc + 1, endOfTown);
            String Place= record.substring(endOfTown + 1, endOfPlace);
            String Start =record.substring(endOfPlace +1, endOfStart);
            mListForm.append(Name + " aged: " + Desc + Town + Place + Start);
```

I have successfully extracted the other data but this does not return anything for the date property can anyone help by giving me the code to extract the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using indexOf and substring multiple times it might be easier to use split.

```
String [] pieces = record.split(";");
```

Then you can access the parts of the record using the array.  Eg:

```
String name = pieces[0];
String desc = pieces[1];
String date = pieces[N];
```

Once you have the date in a String called date, you can call split on that too:

```
String[] dateParts = date.split("/");
```

Then you can use the dateParts array get specific information about the date.  I'm not very familiar with how to store dates/calendars in java but this site probably can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is the DateFormat class. Try looking at [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

You can do something like this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: Yes, SimpleDateFormat should be used for both parsing and formatting of dates, rather then writing it from scratch.